Is it possible to diagonalize the Hadamard product of mutually-diagonalizable PSD matrices?
I've searched around and it seems that little can be said in general about the spectrum of Hadamard (elementwise) products. Thankfully, my problem has structure: Given two mutually-diagonalizable PSD matrices $A=VD_1V^T$ and $B=VD_2V^T$, can anything be said about the spectrum of their Hadamard product? Specifically, I'd like to establish (in)equalities about the diagonal elements of $V^T(A\circ B)V$, maybe something like
$$[V^T(A\circ B)V]_{ii} \geq D_{1,ii}D_{2,ii}.$$
I'd appreciate any insight into this problem. Thanks!
EDIT: Here's what I have so far. Let $v_i$ be the $i$th column of $V$, and let $\alpha, \beta$ index the eigendirections.
$$v_i^T (A\circ B) v_i=v_i^T \sum_{\alpha,\beta} d_{1,\alpha} d_{2,\beta} (v_\alpha \circ v_\beta)(v_\alpha \circ v_\beta)^T v_i= \sum_{\alpha,\beta} d_{1,\alpha} d_{2,\beta} ((v_\alpha \circ v_\beta)^T v_i)^2$$
Here I'm stuck because I don't know if one can say anything about $v_\alpha \circ v_\beta$ given orthonormality, $\langle v_\alpha, v_\beta \rangle = \delta_{\alpha\beta}$.
EDIT 2: I wonder if the problem becomes easier in the high-dimensional limit. If anyone can point me to useful results in this direction, I'd appreciate that too.

Welcome to math SE! As a general rule, questions will be better received if you include information on your attempts to solve the problem. What have you tried here?

Thanks for the pointer, just did.
